# button must be clicked twice to do the action

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I have a problem in my javascript code

Currently, i'm working with symfony2, and I need to use this javascript action

I want, that if the button is clicked, the list will be filled, but the problem is that i need to click on it twice.

that's my code

```
function sellistt() {
    $('#vallc').click(function() {
        $('select#vall > option').prop('selected', true);
    });
}
```

And here the button:

```
<button id="vallc" onclick="sellistt();" class="btn btn-primary">Validate</button>
```

Any suggestion please?
Thanks !

Comment: With the first click you are adding the handler, with the second your are adding the handler again but also executing your `click` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing 2 ways to make something happen when clicking on a button.

With your current code, when clicking on the button you are calling the function `sellistt()` (thanks to the `onclick` attribute on your button element).

And the function `sellistt()` add an EventListener to the button. This EventListener waits for a click on the button to execute this code :

```
$('select#vall > option').prop('selected', true);
```

So the above code will only be executed on the second click.
You only need the EventListener. Just put this part outside of a function :

```
$('#vallc').click(function() {
    $('select#vall > option').prop('selected', true);
});
```

And remove the `onclick` attribute, it's an old practice and not needed at all in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This will be enough,

```
$('#vallc').click(function() {
   $('select#vall > option').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Remove the inline handler from the markup.

---

***what's wrong in your code ?***
On the first click, the event will be bound to that element which is identified by the selector. on the second click the event will be fired normally. but event will fire as many times as the event got registered.